# Hibernate inserts twice when network proxy is used

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using Struts2-spring and Hibernate in our application. We are facing some strange problem. When we use network proxy in browsers and access the application, it inserts every record twice. However if we use browsers with "NO PROXY" settings, it works fine. Can anybody help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the request type. If there is a proxy, the browser might send more HEAD requests to see if the document has really changed. If you changed the request handling code on the server, you may handle these requests like GET.

Example: In Java Servlets, you can override `doGet()` or `service()`. The former gets invoked only for `GET` requests, the latter gets invoked for any type of request (`GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, `DELETE`).

Comment: Additional note: if that is the problem, the appropriate solution is to respect the web standards, and use POST rather than GET for non-idempotent operations like inserts.

Answer (score 0):

check that you are not using the successful method when running proxy i.e.

## without proxy

method1

## with proxy

method1 (and)
method2